# Function creating linked list, deletes it at the end of the run

Tags: c, debugging, linked-list, breakpoints

(English is not my first language, so forgive me)

My code is supposed to go over an assembly file, line by line, and when it finds label in the pattern ':', it supposed to add it as the head of a linked list.

When I tried to debug the function I can actually see that it fills the linked list as planned. but right after the last line of the file, it deletes everything and the head of the of list becomes NULL.

When I tried to put a breakpoint after the loop ends, Visual issued a warning 'This breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associates with this line' .

Here is the code:

```
//function input: 1. files 2.head of linked list
//function finds label in file and add label to linked list 
//function used in the first iteration


void create_labels_list(int argc, char* argv[], label* head)
{
    char newline[MAX_LINE];
    FILE* assem_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    int line_count = 1;//we want to know the number of line of the label so we could get to it when needed
    if (assem_file == NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        while (fgets(newline, MAX_LINE + 1, assem_file) != NULL)//go over the assembly file, line by line
        {
            clean_line(newline, 0); //get rid of all residuals in line
            int i = 0;//index of the chars in the line
            char labelname[50];
            int labelpc = 0;
            for (i; newline[i] != '\0'; i++)//go over the line
            {
                if (newline[i] == ':')//sign that we have a label in the line. if we do, create a new label in the linked list
                {
                    labelpc = line_count;
                    copy_string(labelname, newline, 0, i - 1);
                    head = new_label_in_link_lst(head, labelpc, labelname);
                }
            }
            line_count++;
        }
    }
    fclose(assem_file);
}
```

it worked a few days ago and I don't know what I changed that ruined it.
Thank You!

Comment: I tried to put the breakpoint at the end of the while loop.

Comment: A little too late now, but with a good version control system you could easily track all the changes made (assuming you commit them separately). It also makes it easy to roll back to a previous version. Even for small hobby projects using a VCS is a good habit.

Comment: How are you actually inserting the string value INTO the linked list? It seems that the problem is being caused by a wrong usage of pointers. You need to copy the string into the list note, otherwise it wont work. Please edit the question and insert the linked list data structure as well.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem is here: `void create_labels_list(int argc, char* argv[], label* head)`. In this code the value of the `head` pointer only exists inside the function. After exit from the function the old value which you passed to it will be in effect.

In general you have two ways to work around it:

1. return the value of the pointer from this function, similar to `new_label_in_link_lst`.

```
label *create_labels_list(int argc, char* argv[], label* head) {
   ...
   return head;
}

main () {
   label *head = NULL;
   ...
   head = create_labels_list(..., head);
   ...
}
```

2. or you can pass an address of your head to the function in arguments and use re-direction to update its value.

```
void create_labels_list(int argc, char* argv[], label** head) {
   ...
   *head = new_label_in_link_lst(*head, labelpc, labelname)
   ...
}

main () {
   label *head = NULL;
   ...
   create_labels_list(..., &head);
   ...
}
```

Comment: @Tom, in that case you should mark the answer as accepted.